# Extra horizontal footnote bars without footnote

Tags: footnotes

Has anyone come across the following problem?

I have several footnotes in my document. When I get one on a certain page, sometimes the next page contains a horizontal bar (as there usually is above the footnotes) even though there is no footnote beneath!

[image: horizontal bar on bottom of page]

Does anyone know hot get rid of these lines? Thank you for any help or advice!

Now, here's a sample of the document:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,headings=small,makeidx]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam,polish,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[columns=2,itemlayout=abshang]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand*\de{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
\newcommand*\en{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand*\pl{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{polish}}
\newcommand*\vn{\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont\selectlanguage{vietnam}}

\newcommand{\del}{‚}
\newcommand{\der}{‘}
\newcommand{\dell}{„}
\newcommand{\derr}{“}
\newcommand{\enl}{‘}
\newcommand{\enr}{’}
\newcommand{\enll}{“}
\newcommand{\enrr}{”}
\newcommand{\pll}{‘}
\newcommand{\plr}{’}
\renewcommand{\plll}{„}
\newcommand{\plrr}{”}
\newcommand{\vnl}{‘}
\newcommand{\vnr}{’}
\newcommand{\vnll}{“}
\newcommand{\vnrr}{”}

\newcommand{\expi}{\sffamily\small}
\newcommand{\expo}{\normalfont\normalsize}

\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}
\renewcommand{\textit}[1]{{\sffamily\itshape#1}}

\makeindex

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}

\clearscrheadings
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[]{\sffamily\headmark}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\sffamily\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{\pl xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\subtitle{\pl xxxxxxxxH}
\author{\pl dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa}
\date{}
\publishers{\pl Wxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\ \copyright{} 2015}
\maketitle
\pl \tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\addchap{\pl vfdgs gsdhjdy}

\addsec{\pl gfdxgxfd} \label{gps1801}

\pl Wietnamskie czasowniki nie wyrwebdskżnixuwebdsk strony; nie swebdsk ani czynne, ani bierne. Tym niemniej dafdnak istniejwebdsk sposoby na stworzenie \plll logicznej\plrr\ strony biernej. Do tego celu można użyć dwwebdskch poznanych już wczewebdskniej słwebdskw: \vn \textbf{ujytfdgợc}\index{\vn ujytfdgợc} \pl i~\vn\textbf{bị}\index{\vn bị}.\pl\footnote{Rwebdskżne zastosowania \vn \textbf{ujytfdgợc} \pl i~\vn\textbf{bị} \pl omwebdskwiono na stronie~\pageref{gps1101}.} \pl \uline{Zwrwebdskć uwagę na charakterystyczny szyk zdania.}

\pl Stronę biernwebdsk oddxuemy w sposwebdskb następujwebdskcy:

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Em Tuấn \textbf{ujytfdgợc} khen. & \pl \textit{Tuan dafst chwalony.}\\
\vn Em Tuấn \textbf{ujytfdgợc} mẹ khen. & \pl \textit{Tuan dafst chwalony przez matkę.} \\
\\
\vn Sinh viên \textbf{bị} cô giáo phê bình. & \pl \textit{Student dafst krytykowany przez nauczycielkę.} \\
\\
\vn Bố tôi \textbf{bị} công an phds mfkdsat. & \pl \textit{Mwebdskj ojciec dafst karany przez policjanta.}\\

\end{longtable}

\pl Użyj \vn \textbf{ujytfdgợc}, \pl aby powiedzieć o~czymwebdsk, co uważasz za dobre i~przydafmne, a~\vn\textbf{bị}, \pl aby powiedzieć o~czymwebdsk, co twoim zdaniem dafst złe, nieprzydafmne.\\

\pl Przyjrzyjmy się dafszcze dafdnemu słowu nierzadko używanemu do wyrażania strony biernej: \vn \textbf{do}\index{\vn do} \pl \textit{przez}, \textit{za sprawwebdsk}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tiểu thuyết \vnll Nỗi buồn chiến tranh\vnrr\ \textbf{do} nhà văn Bảo Ninh viết. & \pl \textit{Powiewebdskć \plll Żałowebdskć wojny\plrr\ została napisana przez pisarza Bao Ninh.} \\
\\
\vn Mwebdskn ăn \textbf{do} mẹ tôi nấu ngon lắm. & \pl \textit{Danie ugotowane przez mojwebdsk mamę dafst bardzo smaczne.} \\

\end{longtable}

\addsec{\pl \textit{Stbfxć svcxię}}

\vn \textbf{Trở thành\,/\,trở nên}\index{\vn trở!trở thành}\index{\vn trở!trở nên} \pl znaczy \textit{stsgać się}; dafdnakże \vn \textbf{trở nên} \pl poprzedza przymiotnik bwebdskdź przysłwebdskwek, podczas gdy \vn \textbf{trở thành} \pl poprzedza rzeczownik.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Ngày mai thời tiết sẽ \textbf{trở nên} xấu. & \pl \textit{Jutro pogoda stanie się brzydka.} \\
\\
\vn Sau khi tốt nghiệp ujytds mfkdsai học anh tôi muốn \textbf{trở thành} luật sfdg. & \pl \textit{Po ukończeniu uniwersytetu mwebdskj starszy brat chce zostać prawnikiem.} \\

\end{longtable}

\addsec{\pl\plll\vn Lds mfkdsai\pl\plrr}

\vn \textbf{Lds mfkdsai}\index{\vn lds mfkdsai} \pl dafst czasownikiem oznaczxuwebdskcym \textit{przychodzić}, \textit{przydafżdżać}. Poza swoim podstawowym znaczeniem, \vn \textbf{lds mfkdsai} \pl pełni dafdnak dafszcze kilka istotnych rwebdskl w~gramatyce.

\begin{enumerate}

\item \pl Orzeczenie.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Mời chị \textbf{lds mfkdsai} nhà tôi. & \pl \textit{Zapraszam cię do mnie. (Zapraszam, bywebdsk przyszła do modafgo domu).} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \pl Gdy słowo \vn \textbf{lds mfkdsai} \pl znxududaf się po orzeczeniu, to znaczy ono \textit{ponownie}, \textit{dafszcze raz}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tôi thích quyển sách này. Tôi muốn ujytọc \textbf{lds mfkdsai} quyển sách này. & \pl \textit{Lubię tę ksiwebdskżkę. Chcę dafszcze raz przeczytać tę ksiwebdskżkę.} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \pl Gdy słowo \vn \textbf{lds mfkdsai} \pl poprzedza orzeczenie, to znaczy ono \textit{kontynuować}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Bây giờ tôi mệt lắm, ngày mai tôi \textbf{lds mfkdsai} ujytọc quyển sách này. & \pl \textit{Teraz dafstem bardzo zmęczony; jutro będę dalej czytać tę ksiwebdskżkę.} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \vn \textbf{Lds mfkdsai} \pl używamy rwebdskwniez do wyrażenia zdziwienia, zaskoczenia (gdy cowebdsk dafst niezgodne z~naszymi oczekiwaniami).

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tds mfkdsai sao anh \textbf{lds mfkdsai} nwebdski nhfdg thế? & \pl \textit{Dlaczego mwebdskwisz cowebdsk takiego? (dafstem zaskoczony, że to mwebdskwisz!).} \\
\\
\vn Em Mai ujytã hứa cùng nhau ujyti dds mfkdsao nhfdgng bây giờ \textbf{lds mfkdsai} không cwebdsk thời gian. & \pl \textit{Mai obiecała razem pwebdskjwebdskć na spacer, a~teraz nie ma czasu. (Jak ona tak może!).} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \pl Konstrukcja czasownik +~\vn\textbf{ujyti} +~\pl czasownik +~\vn\textbf{lds mfkdsai}\index{\vn ujyti!ujyti \ldots{} lds mfkdsai@\ldots{} ujyti \ldots{} lds mfkdsai} \pl znaczy \textit{robić cowebdsk wielokrotnie (na okrwebdskgło)}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tôi ujytọc \textbf{ujyti} ujytọc \textbf{lds mfkdsai} bài báo này nhfdgng tôi chfdga hiểu. & \pl \textit{Czytam ten artykuł wielokrotnie, ale wciwebdskż go nie rozumiem.} \\
\\
\vn Anh ấy hỏi \textbf{ujyti} hỏi \textbf{lds mfkdsai} tôi về vấn ujytề này. & \pl \textit{Pyta mnie na okrwebdskgło o~ten problem.} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \vn \textbf{Lds mfkdsai} \pl wchodzi rwebdskwnież w~skład wyrażenia \vn \textbf{\ldots{}\ lds mfkdsai \ldots{}}\ \pl \textit{\ldots{}\ po \ldots{}}\ opisujwebdskcego powtarzanie się czegowebdsk w~kolejnych dafdnostkach czasu.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn ngày \textbf{lds mfkdsai} ngày & \pl \textit{dzień po dniu} \\
\\
\vn tuần \textbf{lds mfkdsai} tuần & \pl \textit{tydzień po tygodniu} \\

\end{longtable}

\pl Podobna konstrukcja, \vn \textbf{ujytã \ldots{} lds mfkdsai \ldots{}}, \pl mxuwebdskca dafdnak inne znaczenie, została omwebdskwiona na stronie \pageref{gps1105}

\end{enumerate}


\backmatter
    \clearpage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{INDEKS}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

This anyway still produces the following:

[image: Horizontal line still there]

Comment: Doesn't usually happen. Please post a small document which produces the problem which we can compile to look into it.

Comment: @cfr I am sorry, as soon as I replace my original text with some dummy text, the problem is gone... I'd rather not post the original here, so I'll to try work it out somehow...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not totally convinced by this change but if I add it to Werner's example the rule on page 2 goes..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=18\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example

\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter
\def\endlongtable{%
  \crcr
  \noalign{%
    \let\LT@entry\LT@entry@chop
    \xdef\LT@save@row{\LT@save@row}}%
  \LT@echunk
  \LT@start
  \unvbox\z@
  \LT@get@widths
  \if@filesw
    {\let\LT@entry\LT@entry@write\immediate\write\@auxout{%
      \gdef\expandafter\noexpand
        \csname LT@\romannumeral\c@LT@tables\endcsname
          {\LT@save@row}}}%
  \fi
  \ifx\LT@save@row\LT@@save@row
  \else
    \LT@warn{Column \@width s have changed\MessageBreak
             in table \thetable}%
    \LT@final@warn
  \fi
  \endgraf\penalty -\LT@end@pen
  \endgroup
  \global\@mparbottom\z@
  \pagegoal\vsize
% change is here
  \ifvoid\footins\else\insert\footins{}\fi
  \endgraf\penalty\z@\addvspace\LTpost
 }

\makeatother
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{Some footnote}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Something & else
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Dominik it's not complex really just changed the order of the two lines marked with the comment, the macro itself is just copied from longtable.sty/

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bug in the [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) package. Here is a minimal example that replicates the behaviour:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paperheight=18\baselineskip]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% Just for this example

\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\footnote{Some footnote}

\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Something & else
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The `longtable` at the end of the page causes a spill-over of the footnote rule if it was on the same page as the `\footnote`. If you wish to avoid this, consider using alternate methods to achieve what you want, since using `longtable` is not all that necessary given your example.

Below I've defined an environment `something` that is just a `tabular` with similar parameters to what you use for `longtable`. Breaking a `longtable` into multiple `something`s would allow you to break it across the page boundary.

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside,titlepage,headings=small]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrpage2,ulem}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[vietnam,polish,english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{longtable,etoolbox,lmodern}

\newenvironment{something}
  {\par
   \leavevmode\hfill
   \begin{tabular}{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}
  }{\end{tabular}}

\newcommand*\de{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
\newcommand*\en{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand*\pl{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\selectlanguage{polish}}
\newcommand*\vn{\fontencoding{T5}\selectfont\selectlanguage{vietnam}}

\newcommand{\del}{‚}
\newcommand{\der}{‘}
\newcommand{\dell}{„}
\newcommand{\derr}{“}
\newcommand{\enl}{‘}
\newcommand{\enr}{’}
\newcommand{\enll}{“}
\newcommand{\enrr}{”}
\newcommand{\pll}{‘}
\newcommand{\plr}{’}
\renewcommand{\plll}{„}
\newcommand{\plrr}{”}
\newcommand{\vnl}{‘}
\newcommand{\vnr}{’}
\newcommand{\vnll}{“}
\newcommand{\vnrr}{”}

\newcommand{\expi}{\sffamily\small}
\newcommand{\expo}{\normalfont\normalsize}

\AtBeginEnvironment{longtable}{\sffamily}
\renewcommand{\textbf}[1]{{\sffamily\bfseries#1}}
\renewcommand{\textit}[1]{{\sffamily\itshape#1}}

\makeindex

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{-\topskip}}

\clearscrheadings
\ihead[]{}
\chead[]{}
\ohead[]{\sffamily\headmark}
\ifoot[]{}
\cfoot[]{}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\sffamily\pagemark}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{\pl xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\subtitle{\pl xxxxxxxxH}
\author{\pl dxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa}
\date{}
\publishers{\pl Wxxxxxxxxxxxxx\\ \copyright{} 2015}
\maketitle
\pl \tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\addchap{\pl vfdgs gsdhjdy}

\addsec{\pl gfdxgxfd} \label{gps1801}

\pl Wietnamskie czasowniki nie wyrwebdskżnixuwebdsk strony; nie swebdsk ani czynne, ani bierne. Tym niemniej dafdnak istniejwebdsk sposoby na stworzenie \plll logicznej\plrr\ strony biernej. Do tego celu można użyć dwwebdskch poznanych już wczewebdskniej słwebdskw: \vn \textbf{ujytfdgợc}\index{\vn ujytfdgợc} \pl i~\vn\textbf{bị}\index{\vn bị}.\pl\footnote{Rwebdskżne zastosowania \vn \textbf{ujytfdgợc} \pl i~\vn\textbf{bị} \pl omwebdskwiono na stronie~\pageref{gps1101}.} \pl \uline{Zwrwebdskć uwagę na charakterystyczny szyk zdania.}

\pl Stronę biernwebdsk oddxuemy w sposwebdskb następujwebdskcy:

\begin{something}
  \vn Em Tuấn \textbf{ujytfdgợc} khen. & \pl \textit{Tuan dafst chwalony.}
\end{something}
\begin{something}
  \vn Em Tuấn \textbf{ujytfdgợc} mẹ khen. & \pl \textit{Tuan dafst chwalony przez matkę.}
\end{something}
\begin{something}
  \vn Sinh viên \textbf{bị} cô giáo phê bình. & \pl \textit{Student dafst krytykowany przez nauczycielkę.}
\end{something}
\begin{something}
  \vn Bố tôi \textbf{bị} công an phds mfkdsat. & \pl \textit{Mwebdskj ojciec dafst karany przez policjanta.}
\end{something}

\pl Użyj \vn \textbf{ujytfdgợc}, \pl aby powiedzieć o~czymwebdsk, co uważasz za dobre i~przydafmne, a~\vn\textbf{bị}, \pl aby powiedzieć o~czymwebdsk, co twoim zdaniem dafst złe, nieprzydafmne.\\

\pl Przyjrzyjmy się dafszcze dafdnemu słowu nierzadko używanemu do wyrażania strony biernej: \vn \textbf{do}\index{\vn do} \pl \textit{przez}, \textit{za sprawwebdsk}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tiểu thuyết \vnll Nỗi buồn chiến tranh\vnrr\ \textbf{do} nhà văn Bảo Ninh viết. & \pl \textit{Powiewebdskć \plll Żałowebdskć wojny\plrr\ została napisana przez pisarza Bao Ninh.} \\
\\
\vn Mwebdskn ăn \textbf{do} mẹ tôi nấu ngon lắm. & \pl \textit{Danie ugotowane przez mojwebdsk mamę dafst bardzo smaczne.} \\

\end{longtable}

\addsec{\pl \textit{Stbfxć svcxię}}

\vn \textbf{Trở thành\,/\,trở nên}\index{\vn trở!trở thành}\index{\vn trở!trở nên} \pl znaczy \textit{stsgać się}; dafdnakże \vn \textbf{trở nên} \pl poprzedza przymiotnik bwebdskdź przysłwebdskwek, podczas gdy \vn \textbf{trở thành} \pl poprzedza rzeczownik.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}
\vn Ngày mai thời tiết sẽ \textbf{trở nên} xấu. & \pl \textit{Jutro pogoda stanie się brzydka.} \\
\\
\vn Sau khi tốt nghiệp ujytds mfkdsai học anh tôi muốn \textbf{trở thành} luật sfdg. & \pl \textit{Po ukończeniu uniwersytetu mwebdskj starszy brat chce zostać prawnikiem.}
\end{longtable}

\addsec{\pl\plll\vn Lds mfkdsai\pl\plrr}

\vn \textbf{Lds mfkdsai}\index{\vn lds mfkdsai} \pl dafst czasownikiem oznaczxuwebdskcym \textit{przychodzić}, \textit{przydafżdżać}. Poza swoim podstawowym znaczeniem, \vn \textbf{lds mfkdsai} \pl pełni dafdnak dafszcze kilka istotnych rwebdskl w~gramatyce.

\begin{enumerate}

\item \pl Orzeczenie.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Mời chị \textbf{lds mfkdsai} nhà tôi. & \pl \textit{Zapraszam cię do mnie. (Zapraszam, bywebdsk przyszła do modafgo domu).} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \pl Gdy słowo \vn \textbf{lds mfkdsai} \pl znxududaf się po orzeczeniu, to znaczy ono \textit{ponownie}, \textit{dafszcze raz}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tôi thích quyển sách này. Tôi muốn ujytọc \textbf{lds mfkdsai} quyển sách này. & \pl \textit{Lubię tę ksiwebdskżkę. Chcę dafszcze raz przeczytać tę ksiwebdskżkę.} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \pl Gdy słowo \vn \textbf{lds mfkdsai} \pl poprzedza orzeczenie, to znaczy ono \textit{kontynuować}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Bây giờ tôi mệt lắm, ngày mai tôi \textbf{lds mfkdsai} ujytọc quyển sách này. & \pl \textit{Teraz dafstem bardzo zmęczony; jutro będę dalej czytać tę ksiwebdskżkę.} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \vn \textbf{Lds mfkdsai} \pl używamy rwebdskwniez do wyrażenia zdziwienia, zaskoczenia (gdy cowebdsk dafst niezgodne z~naszymi oczekiwaniami).

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tds mfkdsai sao anh \textbf{lds mfkdsai} nwebdski nhfdg thế? & \pl \textit{Dlaczego mwebdskwisz cowebdsk takiego? (dafstem zaskoczony, że to mwebdskwisz!).} \\
\\
\vn Em Mai ujytã hứa cùng nhau ujyti dds mfkdsao nhfdgng bây giờ \textbf{lds mfkdsai} không cwebdsk thời gian. & \pl \textit{Mai obiecała razem pwebdskjwebdskć na spacer, a~teraz nie ma czasu. (Jak ona tak może!).} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \pl Konstrukcja czasownik +~\vn\textbf{ujyti} +~\pl czasownik +~\vn\textbf{lds mfkdsai}\index{\vn ujyti!ujyti \ldots{} lds mfkdsai@\ldots{} ujyti \ldots{} lds mfkdsai} \pl znaczy \textit{robić cowebdsk wielokrotnie (na okrwebdskgło)}.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn Tôi ujytọc \textbf{ujyti} ujytọc \textbf{lds mfkdsai} bài báo này nhfdgng tôi chfdga hiểu. & \pl \textit{Czytam ten artykuł wielokrotnie, ale wciwebdskż go nie rozumiem.} \\
\\
\vn Anh ấy hỏi \textbf{ujyti} hỏi \textbf{lds mfkdsai} tôi về vấn ujytề này. & \pl \textit{Pyta mnie na okrwebdskgło o~ten problem.} \\

\end{longtable}

\item \vn \textbf{Lds mfkdsai} \pl wchodzi rwebdskwnież w~skład wyrażenia \vn \textbf{\ldots{}\ lds mfkdsai \ldots{}}\ \pl \textit{\ldots{}\ po \ldots{}}\ opisujwebdskcego powtarzanie się czegowebdsk w~kolejnych dafdnostkach czasu.

\begin{longtable}[r]{p{0.46\linewidth}p{0.46\linewidth}}

\vn ngày \textbf{lds mfkdsai} ngày & \pl \textit{dzień po dniu} \\
\\
\vn tuần \textbf{lds mfkdsai} tuần & \pl \textit{tydzień po tygodniu} \\

\end{longtable}

\pl Podobna konstrukcja, \vn \textbf{ujytã \ldots{} lds mfkdsai \ldots{}}, \pl mxuwebdskca dafdnak inne znaczenie, została omwebdskwiona na stronie \pageref{gps1105}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Other small tweaks to the spacing when the `longtable` problem persists also works. For example, adding `\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}` seems to remove the need for `longtable`'s page-breaking to kick in, and therefore not replicate the footnote rule.

Comment: `if pkg-author == "David Carlisle" status = FEATURE; else status = getStatus();` ;-)

Comment: This is an interesting solution, but it might be not very convenient if there are hundreds of `longtable`s throughout the document. What do you mean by adding `\vspace*{-4\baselineskip}`? Where should I put that?

Comment: @Dominik: I placed it after the "offending" `longtable`.